# adjuntar token a mi base de datos de firebase

Tags: android, firebase

tengo una app conectada con firebase.
cuando un usuario se registra en mi app, los datos se almacena correctamente en mi base de datos pero el token para enviar notificaciones no se esta guardando en la base de datos. solo se ve en consola pero no se sube a firebase.

```
      persona p = new persona();
      FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( 
          RegistroFirebase.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                    String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();

                    Log.e("newToken",newToken);

                    p.setAA_Token(newToken);                    
                    databaseReference.child("1_Usuarios_Registrados").child(p.getAA_Token()).setValue(p);

                }
            });

            
            p.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            p.setA_Nombre(contenidoNombre);
            p.setB_Apellido(contenidoApellido);
            p.setC_Correo(email);
            p.setD_Celular(contenidoCelular);
            databaseReference.child("1_Usuarios_Registrados").child(p.getUid()).setValue(p);



[![Error cuando pongo la variable de newtoken para llevar a base de datos][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk2P6.png
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está que estas guardando tu objeto completo p pero no el token que quieres guardar con getToken

```
databaseReference.child("1_Usuarios_Registrados").child(p.getAA_Token()).setValue(p);
```

si quisieras guardar el token dentro de ese child, deberias escribir el token

```
databaseReference.child("1_Usuarios_Registrados").child(p.getAA_Token()).setValue(p.getAA_Token());
```

Como veo que estas usando el token para usarlo como nodo, lo que yo haria seria crear una clave unica y guardar dentro de esa clave el token, ya que de la forma que lo haces arriba estás duplicando el token tanto para el nodo como para el valor

Entonces quedaría algo asi

```
databaseReference.child("1_Usuarios_Registrados").push().setValue(p.getAA_Token());
```

`push()` genera un nuevo valor alfanumerico único para el valor del token guardado

Comment: hola gracias por la respuesta.
mira pero si yo guardo como tu dices se me guarda el token pero no se me guardaria los otros datos que yo necesito guardar. 

osea como tengo el codigo me funciona y me guarda todos los datos que el usuario esta copiando pero el token se genera pero no sube a la base de datos.
yo se que tengo que poner como hijo para que me suba pero lo que pasa es que si lo pongo asi

Comment: `
p.setAA_Token(newToken);
p.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            p.setA_Nombre(contenidoNombre);
            p.setB_Apellido(contenidoApellido);
            p.setC_Correo(email);
            p.setD_Celular(contenidoCelular);
            databaseReference.child("1_Usuarios_Registrados").child(p.getUid()).setValue(p);`

Comment: si pongo el codigo cómo te mostré en el comentario anterior me sale un error diciendo que no encuentra la variable newToken, ya que esta variable esta metida dentro de otros corchetes y no toma esta variable como para todo el programa. no se si supe explicarte bien